# Spectrum of Laplacian of a compact PseudoRiemannian manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is the Spectrum of Laplacian of a compact PseudoRiemannian manifold discrete?

I know that it should be for Riemannian manifold, but I can't find anything about Pseudo-Riemannian manifold. Does anybody know if the theorem hold and if there are some sort of estimates for the eigenvalues?